# Elixir Returning Smiley Faces on Enum.reverse method

Tags: elixir

I am looking over the [enum](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html) documentation and here is my code:

```
defmodule Math do
  def reverse(list), do: Enum.reverse(list)
end
```

And I run it:

`IO.write(Math.reverse([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))`

But, some weird things are happening. I am receiving a "beep" sound, along with 
 [these funny characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4m3r.png)..

I'm fairly new to Elixir, but I am not sure where to start the debugging process. Where have I gone wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Not for your benefit @MakeWebSocketsGreatAgain but for the benefit of others who may find this question: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/wiki/FAQ (Item 4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is not directly related to the `Enum.reverse/1` function. You could reproduce the exact same thing by simply passing a list of integer to `IO.write/1`:

```
iex(5)> IO.write([8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
^H^G^F^E^D^C^B^A:ok
```

What is happening here is that `IO.write/1` is receiving a list of integer and it treats it as a "char list". A char list can be created when using single quotes, like `'foo'`. Using `i/1` gives us a lot of details:

```
iex(22)> i('foo')
Term
  'foo'
Data type
  List
Description
  This is a list of integers that is printed as a sequence of characters
  delimited by single quotes because all the integers in it represent valid
  ASCII characters. Conventionally, such lists of integers are referred to as
  "char lists" (more precisely, a char list is a list of Unicode codepoints,
  and ASCII is a subset of Unicode).
Raw representation
  [102, 111, 111]
Reference modules
  List
```

I guess that those characters are interpreted weirdly by windows which would cause the sound effect and the "smiley faces".

EDIT: The getting started doc is also really useful: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#utf-8-and-unicode